# Hoare-Ramshaw (two dots) interval notation

Tags: formatting

In a Mma notebook math cell, how can one write an interval with Hoare-Ramshaw (two dots) interval notation?  The obvious answer (\:2025) does not seem to work; two full stops produces odd spacing; and the inferior but crudely acceptable two full-stops surrounded by spaces produces an unwanted times symbol.

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting expression though? Is this only for notation / printing purposes, or do you need *Mathematica* to interpret that format mathematically and operate on it?

Comment: It is only for the text.  (So it will be printed.)

Comment: Can't you simply make the expression a string then? `"(1..3)"` perhaps? Perhaps a bit more context as to your intended use may help us generate better answers.

Comment: Please point to a proper typesetting anywhere online.

Comment: What is the "data type" that you want to display this way? `Interval`? Truth-value expression of the form `a < x < b`?

Comment: Perhaps this is a useful reference: 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Real_Interval  
As for suggested typesetting: 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/iJBW9jERgHI/ROuX8XV9NJUJ  
As for why not just make the expression a string, I suppose I do not understand.  I want the traditional math formatting provided inline in the notebook (e.g., by pressing `ctrl+(` in a text cell).

Comment: There is a `\[DoubleDot]` for this.

Comment: Ooof.  Using \[DoubleDot] feels like a serious abuse.  It's the unicode umlault:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/DoubleDot.html 
That said, it looks decent when abused this way.

Comment: Display bug continues on Windows in v.11.  Reported.

Comment: Display bug continues on Window in v.12.  Reported.

Answer (score 4):

You can type `\:2025` to get the unicode character.

If you prefer to use a keyboard alias, evaluate

```
SetOptions[
  SelectedNotebook[], 
    InputAliases -> 
      Join[Options[SelectedNotebook[], InputAliases][[1, 2]], {"hr" -> "\:2025"}]]
```

in your note book, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>hr<kbd>Esc</kbd> will insert the unicode character `‥` into the cell where you currently typing.

Either way you will be able to produce text cells like

$\qquad$[image: text]

Comment: I mentioned this possibility as not working in the original question.  Do you actually get a display of the character?  If so, what's your version and platform?  I'm using Mma 10.2 on Win 64.

Comment: @Alan. I'm running V10.3.1 on OS X 10.10.2. but it worked in earlier versions as well. I know you mentioned you tried typing in `\:2025` -- my post is meant to tell you that it should work.